# What does the cardinality of a vector space depict?

Tags: linear-algebra

I always assumed that the concept of cardinality is only applicable to sets. Yesterday I read somewhere that the cardinality of a vector space $V$ over a finite field $F$ with $q$ elements equals $q^{\dim V}$.

What exactly does this number represent?

Comment: The cardinality of the set $V$: the number of points in the space.

Comment: Since $V$ is a **set** of vectors, it makes sense to talk about how many vectors it has, i.e. its cardinality. (Of course $V$ is more than just a set, but still.)

Answer (score 7):

Mathematical objects are$^1$ sets with some additional structure. E.g. a group is *a set with a binary operation such that [stuff]*, a ring is *a set with two binary operations such that [stuff]*, and a vector space over a field $k$ is *a set with a binary operation, and a unary operation for every $x\in k$, such that [stuff]*.

When we speak of the cardinality of a mathematical structure, we're referring to the cardinality of the "underlying set" (which is variously called the "carrier set", "domain", "universe", and probably a bunch of other things).

As to the question of how we calculate the cardinality of a vector space over $k$ - well, we're counting the vectors! So let's say I have a field $k$ of cardinality $\kappa$. Then if my vector space $V$ is $n$-dimensional, I can represent a vector in $V$ as an "$n$-tuple" $(a_1, . . . , a_n)$ of elements of my field! So in particular, the number of vectors is $\kappa^n$.

*It turns out we can make sense of this even if the field is infinite, or the space is infinite-dimensional; but that starts getting into some mild set theory.*

---

$^1$Hoo boy. This'll get me in trouble.

The fact is that the statement "Mathematical objects are sets" is a **hugely** loaded proposition, one that many reasonable mathematicians disagree with (including me, depending when you ask). I don't want to get into that here, since that's a topic for another question; but I do want to point out that there is a lot more to that claim than meets the eye. If you're interested, here's a few terms you might want to look up:

- Set-theoretic foundations
- Structural set theory
- Non-concrete categories

But these are fairly advanced topics, and might best wait 'till later. Tl;dr, it's not really fair to just say "mathematical objects are sets," but right now it's probably a decent approximation of the truth.